# Is there a way to pass embedded arguments and normal arguments together in one keyword in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am facing one problem in which i want to add embedded arguments as well as normal arguments but while adding i am getting an error that we are not able to add both embedded arguments as well as normal arguments in the same keyword.

My question are as following :

1. Is there any way to add both arguments in the script ?
2. If yes , then how we are going to do that ?

Comment: Can you provide your code and exact error you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you the truth, you can't use both embedded arguments and traditional arguments.

The [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name) says this about it:

> Keywords using embedded arguments cannot take any "normal" arguments (specified with [Arguments] setting) but otherwise they are created just like other user keywords.